# Office API Javascript - Loading error telemetryproxy.html not found

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I tried to load Office.js to my application.

I've added the `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

and I get warning and error in console.

```
Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client
```

and Error: `o15apptofilemappingtable.js:11 GET https://telemetryservice.firstpartyapps.oaspapps.com/telemetryservice/telemetryproxy.html 404 (Not Found)`

I created app.js contains:

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    switch (reason) {
        case 'inserted': console.log('The add-in was just inserted.');
        case 'documentOpened': console.log('The add-in is already part of 
              the document.');
    }
  });
};
```

Someone can help me please how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is expected when you try to open the add-in in a browser page. Office.js will only work inside an Office application, such as in a task pane. To run an add-in that you are developing, you need to sideload it into an Office application. If you are working with Visual Studio, you can just press F5. If you are working with a different editor, you need to use one of the sideloading techniques. For details, see [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins).

The second error is probably a side effect of the first one.